# How to go to other view Controller using Navigation Bar Item?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

[image]
This is my TableViewController: Cells will segue to First controller

```
    import UIKit

class SubjectsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var subjectImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var subjectName: UILabel!
}

class AddQuestionTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var Subjects = ["Geology", "Mathematics", "Computer", "English", "History", "Science"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (Subjects.count)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "pickedSubjectSegue", sender: Subjects[indexPath.row])
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let next = segue.destination as! SubViewController
        next.myLabel = sender as! String
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SubjectsTableViewCell


        cell.subjectName?.text = Subjects[indexPath.row]
        cell.subjectImage?.image = UIImage(named: (Subjects[indexPath.row] + ".jpeg"))

        return cell
    }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

How can I move to second view controller using the Add navigation bar item?

What I tried: ctrl + dragging then modal - failed.

Should I use action or segue? But i already use segue in the table cells.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect `seque` to `second view controller` and give it a name other than the segue that is connected to `first view controller` i.e. `pickedSubjectSegue`

**Example:** "`secondSegue`"

Then in `prepareSegue` method check the identifiers of both segues before performing any operation:

**Code:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier = "pickedSubjectSegue"
        {
            let next = segue.destination as! SubViewController
            next.myLabel = sender as! String
        }
        else
        {
            //Write your code here
        }
    }
```